# AWS Lambda Database Connection works with PyMySQL but not SQLAlchemy

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, sqlalchemy, proxy, pymysql

I am trying to connect to a MySQL RDS Database using Lambda Functions. I have tested this locally through SAM invoke and it works. I am now testing it on the AWS Lambda Console and it does not work.
I cannot connect using SQLAlchemy using the PyMYSQL engine, but I can connect using the PyMYSQL Library.

I generate my database_token through:

```
database_token = rds_client.generate_db_auth_token(
    DBHostname=os.environ["DB_HOST"],
    Port=3306,
    DBUsername=os.environ["DB_USER"],
    Region=os.environ["AWS_REGION"],
)
```

I then can connect to the database through PyMySQl using:

```
database_connection = pymysql.connect(
    host=os.environ["DB_HOST"],
    port=3306,
    database=os.environ["DB_NAME"],
    user=os.environ["DB_USER"],
    password=database_token,
    ssl={"any_non_empty_dict": True},
)
```

But when I use SQLAlchemy using this code block:

```
DB_URL = f"mysql+pymysql://{os.environ['DB_USER']}:{database_token}@{os.environ['DB_HOST']}:3306/{os.environ['DB_NAME']}"
engine = create_engine(DB_URL, connect_args = {'ssl':{"any_non_empty_dict": True}}, echo=True)
database_connection = engine.connect()
```

I am returned this error:

```
(pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1045, "Access denied for user 'DB_USER'@'***.***.***.***' (using password: NO)")
```

When I replace the HOST name and the PASSWORD with credentials for the database itself and not the Proxy. SQLAlchemy is able to connect. It is only during a connection attempt to the Proxy.

Is there a difference in the configuration of the PyMYSQl engine while using SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the passowrd and username need to be url encoded not sure about username but i can confirm the password need to be encoded from this [issue](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/5227#issuecomment-608426292).

Comment: Great, that worked! Thank you! 

It was confusing because it was working locally but not on the console.

Comment: @BenSlater cool ! it propebly worked because the you used the password which did not have wierd charachter to be encoded. could you please marked as accepted answer and mark it as resolved.